# Using an empty string in path fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node API i have some function that updates the email address Array of either a contact or a farm, its the same concept but the difference is where the array is located in farms is in Records.emails and in Contacts its in emails. So in my case I decide based on _type what the path is.

```
  if(result.content._type === "farm") {
      emailPath = 'Record'
      emailPathFull = 'Record.emails'

    } else {
      emailPath = ''
      emailPathFull = 'emails'
    }
    
   var e_emails = result.content[emailPath].emails;
```

In case the emailPath is '' which happens to be the case for Contact it cant get the data. So i am wondering if there is a way to make this work other then using

```
 if(result.content._type === "farm"){
     e_emails = result.content.Record.emails;}
  else {
     e_emails = result.content.emails;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that, and more so, you don't need too.

1. Define a variable that will receive the value of emails.
2. Use the conditional to disambiguate the input
3. Copy the emails from where it resides in the input, based on type

```
let e_emails

if(result.content._type === "farm") {
  e_emails = result.content.Record.emails
} else {
  e_emails = result.content.emails
}
    
console.log(e_emails)
```